# How to know the mapping of transitivity result to node in R

Tags: r, igraph

I wish to get the clustering coefficient for every node in a graph. The following code is giving me the result. However, I want this to be as a dataframe where one column gives the node name and the other column gives the measure.

```
 transitivity(graph_df,type = "local", vids = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create this yourself:

```
vertex_names = function (g) {
    vert = V(g)
    if (! is.null(names(vert))) names(vert) else as.vector(vert)
}

trans = data.frame(Vertex = vertex_names(graph_df),
                   Transitivity = transitivity(graph_df, type = 'local', vids = NULL))
```

`V` returns the verices of a graph but the result object is of a class that can’t be used directly as a data.frame column; `vertex_names` takes care of that.